# Install Pyoptsparse

Tags: optimization, conda

I am trying to install pyoptsparse. In order to do that, I set a Conda environment on PyCharm. Then I added conda-forge channel, where the pyoptsparse package should be, but when I am trying to install it through the command : conda install pyoptsparse , it always returns me that the package does not exist.

Has someone already faced to this same problem?
I may precise that I am using a Windows machine.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyoptsparse

https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/install.html#requirements) states that Windows is not supported. Either run through WSL or attempt installing through `pip`.

However, attempting to install through `pip` appears to fail during compilation for the **win-64** platform, at least when using the following environment:

[image: so-pyoptsparse]

**so-pyoptsparse.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-pyoptsparse
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy
  - sqlitedict >=1.6
  - scipy >=1.2
  - mdolab-baseclasses >=1.3.1
  - swig
  - compilers
  - pip
  - pip:
    - git+https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse.git@v2.8.2
```

Details on how it fails can be found in the logs of [the GitHub Workflow run](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/actions/runs/2234190067).